# sbt stage does not include all configs from submodules

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following setup of a Scala application :

```
Application
|
|--> /ApplicationA
|   -> /conf
|   -> /build.sbt
| 
|--> /ApplicationB
|   -> /conf
|   -> /build.sbt
|
|-> /conf
|-> /build.sbt
```

Whole *Application* depends on *ApplicationA* and *ApplicationB*. While I'm doing `sbt clean stage` I'm receiving a build with *conf* folder which is containing only conf files from main *conf* folder and do not contains any files from `/ApplicationA/conf` or `/ApplicationB/conf`.

So, is it an option to include such files into the build during `sbt clean stage`?

Comment: Just to be sure - those configs don't happen to have exactly the same names like e.g. `application.conf`?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok no, they don't. Also, I found , when I'm running `sbt clean stage` so I receive this configs under the `/ApplicationA/target\universal\stage\conf'` and `/ApplicationB/target\universal\stage\conf'` but I need them be accessible when I'm running my main application after `sbt clean stage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the workaround it was created an additional sbt task which is running before `sbt clean stage`. This task takes all config files and copies them into `Application/conf` folder and adds a comment in the top of each file, that this file is auto generated.